# How do I compress an HTML/JAVASCRIPT/CSS web page to be used with a web server running on an embedded device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, embedded, embeddedwebserver

I am building a web page that will be served by an embedded device (probably an ESP32) via wifi. Because users of my device won't necessarily have an internet connection, I can't use any CDN's and I am forced to include all libraries (Bootstrap etc) on the device and the webpage has gotten too big to fit on the device. Is there a way I can compress all of the files for the webpage so they take up less space? Due to speed and processing power limitation of my device, the decompression of these files would have to take place on the browser side after being received. Is there a way to do this?

I am an embedded guy not a web dev guy, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a filesystem that supports compression, like btrfs. For faster decompression use it with zstd compression method.